# Как получить данные из локального файла?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

Нужно получить код файла svg для вставки на страницу.
Пытался сделать по [этому](http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) ничего не получилось.
Подскажите как сделать?
Сам файл получить получается,в переменную f. но как содержание файла поймать не понимаю(

Comment: Если вы пытались что-то сделать, то покажите здесь код, прямо в вопросе. Или дайте ссылку на демо, например, на jsfiddle.com. Тогда нам всем будет легче поправить ваш рабочий код, а не решать вашу проблему с нуля. Иначе вы рискуете остаться без ответа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример чтения и вывода картинки на страницу:

```js
var inputElement = document.getElementById('input'),
    svgImage = document.getElementById('svgImage');

inputElement.onchange = function() {

  var fileList = this.files,
      svgFile = fileList[0],
      reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function(event) {
    // Выводим картинку
    var data = event.target.result;
    svgImage.src = data;
  };

  reader.onerror = function() {
    alert('Ошибка чтения файла!');
  };

  // Читаем наш файл как base64
  reader.readAsDataURL(svgFile);

};
```

```html
<input id="input" type="file">
<hr>
<img id="svgImage">
```

Подробнее о `FileReader` можно почитать на MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: Для svg логичнее было бы `readAsText()`.

Comment: @Qwertiy можно, но если нет никаких манипуляций с самим содержимым файла, то особого смысла нет, да и svg текст тогда придётся конвертировать при помощи `DOMParser()`.

Comment: **Смысл.** 1. Текст короче, чем он же в base64, а длина url ограничена. 2. С текстом можно как-то работать, а с base64 - нет. **Конвертирование.** Не придётся: `"data:image/svg," + svgText`. Хотя, подумал ещё и вощникли некторорые сомнения по поводу переводов строк...